# Split a pandas dataframe header into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to split the dataframe header `id;signin_count;status` into more columns where I can put my data into. I've tried `df.columns.values`, but I couldn't get a string to use `.split` in, as I was hoping. Instead, I got:

```
Index(['id;signin_count;status'], dtype='object')
```

Which returns `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'split'` when I try `.split`

In broader terms, I have:

```
id;signin_count;status
0   353;20;done;
1   374;94;pending;
2   377;4;done;
```

And want:

```
    id      signin_count  status
0   353     20            done
1   374     94            pending
2   377     4             done
```

Splitting the data itself is not the problem here, that I can do. The focus is on how to access the header names without hardcoding it, as I will have to do the same with any other dataset with the same format

From the get-go, thank you

Comment: You can use `df.columns[0].split(';')`. `columns` render a list of values, in your case, all you need is the first value.

Comment: M_S_N answered your root problem, you'll probably end up creating new dfs for every split since all the data shape changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are reading your data from a csv file you can define `sep` to `;` and read it as:

```
df=pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep=';', index_col=False)
```

Output:

```
    id  signin_count    status
0   353     20  done
1   374     94  pending
2   377     4   done
```

Comment: Thanks! It's way easier than what I was trying to do